# How to convert MongoDB $group and count/$sum aggregation to a Java Object using Aggregation?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB query, which allows you to sum `status` field and get Documents yearly:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                year: { 
                        $year: "$createdAt" 
                },
                status: "$status"
            },
            count: { 
                     $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },
    { $replaceWith: { $mergeObjects: [ "$_id", "$$ROOT" ] } },
    { $unset: "_id" }
])
```

I want to translate it into `Java Aggregation` and send query with `MongoOperations`.
I'm doing it like that:

```java
GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group(Fields.fields("$createdAt")).sum(String.valueOf(1)).as("yearly");
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(groupOperation);
AggregationResults<String> strings = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, "collection", String.class);
```

But it's not working.
Can someone help me with a solution to this problem?

I try many ways, with `count`, `sum`, but it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
AggregationResults<Object> results = mongoOperations.aggregate(
            Aggregation.newAggregation(
                    Aggregation.project("status").and(DateOperators.Year.yearOf("createdAt")).as("year"),
                    Aggregation.group(
                            Fields.from(
                                    Fields.field("year", "year"),
                                    Fields.field("status", "status")
                            )
                    ).count().as("count"),
                    ReplaceWithOperation.replaceWithValueOf(
                            ObjectOperators.MergeObjects.mergeValuesOf("$_id").mergeWith("$$ROOT")
                    ),
                    UnsetOperation.unset("_id")
            ),
            "collection",
            Object.class
    );
```

Comment: ReplaceWithOperation/ObjectOperators/UnsetOperation, can not find these classes

Comment: Not working.
It gives me too many statuses and an incorrect amount of them

Comment: ReplaceWithOperation/ObjectOperators/UnsetOperation are imported from -
`import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.*`

As per your question you were trying to `group` using both `createdAt` & `status` [combination group] so ofcourse you will be getting too many statuses. What is it you were trying to achieve ?

Comment: I try to get documents by every year in the spring framework using ``Aggregation`` class

Comment: check the updated answer. Have added Project stage before Group

Comment: Now it's working, you are the best! <3